# What's the connection between the Red Sandalwood and the Deví (Shakti)?

Tags: belief, devi, japa, japamala

I have heard at several places the intrinsic link between the Deví (Durga/Uma/Shakti) and the Red Sandalwood (*Rakta-Chandan* - रक्त चंदन ).

Several "*pandits*" or astrologers advice doing the *jaapam-dhyaanam* for the Deví (or her manifestations) using the Red Sandalwood based rosary, for maximum benefits.

So, what's the religio-theological connection between the Deví and Red Sandalwood?